# Scraping Pricing off a search Bar - site link changed

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, request

With the help of some experts here I was able to build a scraper that works fine.

The essential line of code is really:

```py
data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
r = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data).json()"
```

However the site recently changed their link from partsfinder.com to partssource.com, and the code longer seems to work.

Just wondering if there's a trick I can use on my original code to have it working again.

Any thoughts is appreciated, thanks!

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\Part Number Input.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Product code'])
9
i = 0

Total_rows = PN.shape[0]
partnumlist = []
partnumlist1 = []
partnumlist2 = []
partnumlist3 = []
partnumlist4 = []
partnumlist5 = []

while i < Total_rows:

         data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
         r = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data).json()

         partnumlist.append(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data1 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17475"}}
         r1 = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data1).json()

         partnumlist1.append(r1['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data2 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "16880"}}
         r2 = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data2).json()

         partnumlist2.append(r2['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data3 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "47221"}}
         r3 = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data3).json()

         partnumlist3.append(r3['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data4 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17045"}}
         r4 = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data4).json()

         partnumlist4.append(r4['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data5 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17055"}}
         r5 = requests.post('https://www.partssource.com/catalog/Service', json=data5).json()

         partnumlist5.append(r5['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         i=i+1

list_of_dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(partnumlist),pd.DataFrame(partnumlist1),
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist2), pd.DataFrame(partnumlist3),
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist4), pd.DataFrame(partnumlist5)]

pd.concat(list_of_dataframes).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output25.csv')
```

Comment: if they change ulr then maybe they changed other elements and  first you have to analyze this page using `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab: `network`) to see what else you have to change in your code.

Comment: BTW: you can do `PN = df[['Product code']]` or even you can select columns when you read file  `PN = pd.read_excel(..., usecols=['Product code'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` I created this code.

Page use different url, send different data, get result with different keys.

You would have to use `DevTools` to observe more requests from browser to server to recognize how to use more params in `data`

```
import requests

query = "mobile"

data = {
#    "facets":[{
#        "name":"OEM",
#        "value":"GE%20Healthcare"
#    }],
    "facets":[],    
    "facilityId": 38451,
    "id_ins": "a2a3d332-73a7-4194-ad87-fe7412388916",
    "limit": 15,
    "query": query,
    "referer": "/catalog/Service",
    "start": 0,
#    "urlParams":[{
#        "name": "OEM",
#        "value": "GE Healthcare"
#    }],
    "urlParams":[]    
}

r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=data)
data = r.json()

#print(data['products'])
#print(data['products'][0])
#print(data['products'][0]['options'])
#print(data['products'][0]['options'][0])

print(data['products'][0]['options'][0]['price'])
```

---

**EDIT (2020.09.01)**

If you have manu queries then use `for`-loop to run the same code many times but with different query. And when you get data for one query then use `for`-loop to get all prices from `data['products']`

**EDIT (2020.09.06)**

I added variable `start` and `limit` in `get_data()` and later I run it in loop `for start in range(0, limit*10, limit)` to get 10 pages (every with 100 elements)

```
import requests
# import pprint  # to format data on screen `pprint.pprint()

# --- fucntions ---

def get_data(query, start=0, limit=15): # <-- new (2020.09.06)
    """Get data from server"""
    
    payload = {
    #    "facets":[{
    #        "name":"OEM",
    #        "value":"GE%20Healthcare"
    #    }],
        "facets":[],    
        "facilityId": 38451,
        "id_ins": "a2a3d332-73a7-4194-ad87-fe7412388916",
        "limit": limit,  # <-- new (2020.09.06)
        "query": query,
        "referer": "/catalog/Service",
        "start": start,  # <-- new (2020.09.06)
    #    "urlParams":[{
    #        "name": "OEM",
    #        "value": "GE Healthcare"
    #    }],
        "urlParams":[]    
    }

    r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
    data = r.json()
    
    return data

def show_data(data):
    #print(data['products'])
    #print(data['products'][0])
    #print(data['products'][0]['options'])
    #print(data['products'][0]['options'][0])

    print(data['products'][0]['options'][0]['price'])

    for item in data['products']:
        #pprint.pprint(item)
        print('title:', item['title'])
    
        if not item['options']:
            print('price: unknown')
        else:
            for option in item['options']:
                print('price:', option['price'], '| vendor item number:', option['vendorItemNumber'])

        print('---')
    
def filter_data(data):
    filtered = []
    
    for item in data['products']:
        if not item['options']:
            filtered.append( [] )  # unknown
        else:
            all_prices = [option['price'] for option in item['options']]
            filtered.append( all_prices )
            
    return filtered
    
# --- main ---

all_queries = ["mobile", 'GE Healthcare']

limit = 100  # <-- new (2020.09.06)

for query in all_queries:

    # pagination
    for start in range(0, limit*10, limit): # <-- new (2020.09.06)

        print('\n--- QUERY:', query, 'start:', start, '---\n')

        data = get_data(query, start, limit)
        #show_data(data)

        filtered = filter_data(data)
        print(filtered)
```

Comment: thanks!  I actually only need price.   Could you possibly make some changes to the code above so that when I input a list of part numbers and the output will be a list of prices?  taking GE healthcare as an example is fine, wish to understand the code better

Comment: if you have many elements then use `for`-loop to run code many times with different query. And for every query use `for-loop to get all prices from `data['products']` I put new example

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot.  I have one more question: how can I also show part number in the result as well?  I tried to append it at the end : print('price:', option['price'], '| vendor item number:', option['vendorItemNumber'], 'part number', option['partNumber']) but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: use `print(option)` or `print(option.keys())` to see what is in `option`. I don't see `partNumber` in `option`. Do the same for `item` and you see `partNumber`. You have to use `item['partNumber']`

Comment: great I got it to work!  I made some changes now my code returns an excel sheet with part number and price for each part.  However I run into the below issue when changing the limit to 500+:  "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None JSONDecodeError: Expecting value"  Is there a way to avoid this?  As I will be going through a pretty large data size.  Thanks for your support

Comment: maybe server has limit 500 and you can't change it. But maybe you should check if `start` is used to pagining data. Maybe if you use `start: 500` then you get result from 500 to 1000, and for `start:1000` maybe you get from 1000 to 1500, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will be creating another post for this,

Comment: it would need only simple loop ie. `for start in range(0, 5000, 500): data = get_data(query, start)` and then you would have to use this value in `payload = {'start': start, ...}`. I added this in last code in answer.

Comment: The code stops at around 10000+ item when I expand the range to 10k+ with the error below.  Would you know the cause for this?  File "C:\Users\212677036\Documents\anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting valu

Comment: error can mean that server doesn't send JSON data. You should use `print( r.text )` to see what you get from server. Maybe there is warning for bots/script or captcha. You could save `r.text` in file `.html` and open in web browser to better see what you get.