# Scraping Pricing off a search Bar - reached server limit

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, request

With help on Stackoverflow, I was able to come up with the scraper.  The code returns a list of part numbers and its corresponding prices.

part1 price1
part2 price2
...
...
partn pricen

However the website seems to only allow 200 requests - when i raise the limit to 200+ i would get the error: "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None JSONDecodeError: Expecting value".

I just want to know if there's a way to avoid this error?  If not I can raise start:0 by 200 each time, but since I would have 100k+ items easily it won't be very efficient..is there a way I can loop the limit and the start function?

Please see the codes below, any help appreciated!

```
import requests
# import pprint  # to format data on screen `pprint.pprint()

import pandas as pd
# --- fucntions ---

def get_data(query):
    """Get data from server"""
    
    payload = {
    #    "facets":[{
    #        "name":"OEM",
    #        "value":"GE%20Healthcare"
    #    }],
        "facets":[],    
        "facilityId": 38451,
        "id_ins": "a2a3d332-73a7-4194-ad87-fe7412388916",
        "limit": 200,
        "query": query,
        "referer": "/catalog/Service",
        "start": 0,
    #    "urlParams":[{
    #        "name": "OEM",
    #        "value": "GE Healthcare"
    #    }],
        "urlParams":[]    
    }

    r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
    data = r.json()
    
    return data

           
            

all_queries = ['GE Healthcare']
for query in all_queries:
   #print('\n--- QUERY:', query, '---\n')
    data = get_data(query)
    Part_Num = []
    Vendor_Item_Num = []
    price = []

    for item in data['products']:
        
        if not item['options']:
            Part_Num.append([])
            Vendor_Item_Num.append([])
            price.append([])
        else:
            all_prices = [option['price'] for option in item['options']]
            all_vendor = [option['price'] for option in item['options']]
            all_part_num = item['partNumber']
            
            Part_Num.append(all_part_num)
            Vendor_Item_Num.append(all_vendor)
            price.append(all_prices)
    
list_of_dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(Part_Num),pd.DataFrame(price)]
pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=1).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output7.csv')
```

Comment: You can have 200 requests per day or something or you can have maximum 200 requests in parallel?

Comment: in parallel I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check the `status_code` that your `request` was successful.  The API is giving HTTP 500 when limit is > 200. [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).  You need to study the documentation of the API.   Many APIs limit requests per second and maximum request size so they can maintain a reliable service.

The `json()` method will fail if the HTTP request was not successful.

You can get data in batches.  Sample code below I stop because I have no want to stay in the loop for 500+ iterations...  You could consider using threading so it's not so sequential.

All of this is covered in [SO prodasf-vip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437946/scraping-pricing-off-a-search-bar-site-link-changed)

```
import requests
query = 'GE Healthcare'
payload = {
        "facets":[],    
        "facilityId": 38451,
        "id_ins": "a2a3d332-73a7-4194-ad87-fe7412388916",
        "limit": 200,
        "query": query,
        "referer": "/catalog/Service",
        "start": 0,
        "urlParams":[]    
    }

r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
if r.status_code == 200:
    js = r.json()
    
df = pd.json_normalize(js["products"])
while len(df) < js["totalResults"] and len(df)<2000:
    payload["start"] += 200
    r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(r.json()["products"])])
    else:
        break
    print(f"want: {js['totalResults']} got: {len(df)}")
df
```

Comment: Yeah looks like the request size is limited to 200..is there a way I can request the data in loads of 200 each so they limitation error is not triggered?

Comment: I've updated - but as noted it's leg work of understanding the API you are using.  No escaping read-the-manual :-)

Comment: As this is a side project I've only got time to run it now..I changed len(df) to <200,000, the code works well, however there's supposed to be 106,732 total, the code stopped at 10,200 results - last line of print: "want: 106732 got: 10200".  Not sure what might have caused this?  Any answer appreciated, thanks!